# When do we write a new Controller in Asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When should I create new Controller class in Asp.net MVC (Design Question)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079866/when-should-i-create-new-controller-class-in-asp-net-mvc-design-question)

I'm relatively new to `ASP.net MVC` and I was looking into the code of some application. I haven't given much of a thought for it earlier but when do we require a new `controller`? Are there any best practices regarding this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably a duplicate question - [When should I create new Controller class in Asp.net MVC (Design Question)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079866/when-should-i-create-new-controller-class-in-asp-net-mvc-design-question)...

...but, common practice is a new controller per resource, so for example, one for management of users, one for management of bookings etc. Then on each controller you'll have actions for add, modify, delete.

Comment: @sandeepKNJ: are you using MVC?